# AWS Toolkit was unable to verify the contents of the aws.deploy.tools tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2022, aws-toolkit

I have installed AWS toolkit as an extensions from Visual studio 2022

When i want to start "Publish to AWS..." on a Project I got a message box

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5QV5.png

And the following message in output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcmSY.png

Unable to open the Publish to AWS dialog: AWS Toolkit was unable to verify the contents of the aws.deploy.tools tool.
Restart Visual Studio to try again.

the log is behind

2023-04-27 11:53:45,305 [1] ERROR Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws - Failed to open the Publish document
System.InvalidOperationException: AWS Toolkit was unable to verify the contents of the aws.deploy.tools tool.
Restart Visual Studio to try again.
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.ProcessExitHandler.Execute()
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.VerifyDeployCli.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.DeployCli.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.DeployCli.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<g__Verify|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Telemetry.TelemetryLoggerExtensionMethods.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.DeployCli.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.DeployCli.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAwsPackage.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Models.PublishDialogStepProcessor.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<g__Show|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Telemetry.TelemetryLoggerExtensionMethods.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.d__7.MoveNext()
2023-04-27 11:54:52,624 [1] ERROR Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws - Failed to open the Publish document
System.InvalidOperationException: AWS Toolkit was unable to verify the contents of the aws.deploy.tools tool.
Restart Visual Studio to try again.
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.ProcessExitHandler.Execute()
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.VerifyDeployCli.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.DeployCli.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.DeployCli.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<g__Verify|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Telemetry.TelemetryLoggerExtensionMethods.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.DeployCli.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Install.DeployCli.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAwsPackage.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Models.PublishDialogStepProcessor.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<g__Show|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Telemetry.TelemetryLoggerExtensionMethods.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.AWSToolkit.Publish.Package.PublishToAws.d__7.MoveNext()
2023-04-27 11:57:54,195 [6] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.Telemetry.Internal.TelemetryPublisher - Publishing 5 event(s)
2023-04-27 11:58:59,259 [84] DEBUG Amazon.AWSToolkit.Telemetry.Internal.TelemetryPublisher - Telemetry Publisher loop has stopped.

i tried to restart vs and the laptop

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Deploy tool used by Publish to AWS is vended through NuGet.

You can try to run `dotnet tool install -g aws.deploy.tools` from the command line, to see if your system is configured to download and install the deploy tool.

Another thing you can try is to see what NuGet sources your system is configured with. From Visual Studio, select the Tools menu, NuGet Package Manager, Package Manager Settings, Package Sources. You should have a NuGet package source configured in there (currently this would look like `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`), and it should be enabled with a check mark beside it.

Your toolkit log may have some lines of text above the "AWS Toolkit was unable to verify the contents of the aws.deploy.tools tool" line which could also help determine the problem. Is it possible to share additional details from the log?